# angular2 coding environment setup

Tags: angular, npm-install

I'm trying to set up a coding environment for angular2. I tried to run an `npm install` on the `package.json` file. As you can see below, it isn't working very well, the code below is what I received after running the `npm install`. I know that error 404 means that it couldn't find the age but I still don't know how to fix the problem. If someone could explain to me how to fix all of these errors it would be very helpful. I'm also open to an alternative solution to this problem. If it helps I'm still on windows XP (I don't know if this changes anything for the solution).

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2016.3.3\bin\runnerw.exe" 
                    "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program             
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" install
npm WARN package.json angular2-seed@1.0.0 scripts['server'] should  
       probably be scripts['start'].
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular2-in-memory-web-api
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap
(...)
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular2-in-memory-web-api
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/reflect-metadata
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular2-router-loader
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular2-template-loader
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/zone.js
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/core-js
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/css-loader
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/raw-loader
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/to-string-loader
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/awesome-typescript-loader
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ie-shim
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/common
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/compiler
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/forms
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/compiler-cli
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/core
npm ERR! 404 Not Found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'angular/common' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'angular2-seed'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 5.1.2600
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program  
 Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My 
      Documents\Programming\angular2-seed-master\angular2-seed-master
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! code E404
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack-merge
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platform-server
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/http
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platform-browser
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platform-browser-dynamic
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/router
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack-dev-server
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/types/node
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/upgrade

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: tarball a folder and report a bug to the author

Answer (score 1):

The version of Angular 2 you are using is not provided anymore. You should initiate a new Angular2 project using [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/).

You need to install it using the command `npm install -g @angular/cli` then you initiate a new project using the command `ng new your-project-name`.

Comment: `npm ERR! addLocal Could not install angular/cli                                   npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\angular\cli'                                                           npm ERR! If you need help you may report this *entire* log                                              npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:                                npm ERR! <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>                                       npm ERR! System Windows_NT 5.1.2600        npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\`

Comment: `\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js""install" "-g" "@angular/cli" npm ERR! cwd C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28  npm ERR! npm -v v1.4.9  npm ERR! path C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\angular\cli  npm ERR! code ENOENT  npm ERR! errno 34  npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:  npm ERR!       C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\npm-debug.log  npm ERR! not ok code 0 `

Comment: Could you check that you have the last version of node v6.9.5 (with npm 3.10.10)? I see that the install folder is angular/cli, are you sure you are installing the package @angular/cli and not angular/cli? To be sure you use the last version try the following `npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli`, then `npm cache clean`and finally `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, type `ng init` in the console. It will install few important files, needed for `npm install` process, like `package.json`. Then, use `npm install` command.

Comment: Ok I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: `C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Programming\angular2-seed-m
aster>ng init
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
`

Comment: Do you have `node` and `npm` installed?

Comment: Yeah, when I check to see if their installed it says they are.